# How to tell SchemaValidation fatal and errors are ok and still get details of validation errors?

Tags: jakarta-ee, xsd, java-8, jax-ws, xsd-validation

I have a `@Webservice` that requires XSD validation of the input. 
Both `inputTime` and `userInput` of `PingInput` are required in my WSDL XSD.

I decorate my webservice with `@SchemaValidation` with a custom `SchemaValidationErrorHandler` as below.

Because my `SchemaValidationErrorHandler` methods below only do a `packet.invocationProperties.put` and don't throw an exception , I am expecting that when ping is called, it should still enter my ping method.

What do I need to do to enable this behavior ?

**Webservice :**

```
@WebService
@Stateless
@SchemaValidation(handler = SchemaValidationErrorHandler.class)  
class MyWebservice {
  public PingResponse ping(PingInput input) throws PingFault{
    //never gets here when there is a XSD error
    Object errorException = messageContext.get(SchemaValidationErrorHandler.ERROR);  
...
  }
}
```

**SchemaValidationErrorHandler :**

```
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.ValidationErrorHandler;  
public class SchemaValidationErrorHandler extends ValidationErrorHandler {  

  public static final String WARNING = "Warning";  
  public static final String ERROR = "Error";  
  public static final String FATAL_ERROR = "Fatal";  

  public void warning(SAXParseException exception) {  
    packet.invocationProperties.put(WARNING, exception);  
  }  

  public void error(SAXParseException exception) {  
    packet.invocationProperties.put(ERROR, exception);  
  }  

  public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) {  
    packet.invocationProperties.put(FATAL_ERROR, exception);  
  }
```

**Input:**

```
class PingInput {
  long inputTime;//required
  String userInput;//required
}
```

Comment: Seems this relates to the jaxws-rt I was using. 2.2.10 works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent more than half a day trying to get this to work, so I am posting an answer. I hope it helps someone else.

It seems that the JavaWS bundled with my application server was the problem.

After including the below dependency in my WAR , it worked like a charm. 
Previously I marked it as provided.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
  version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```